# Application error running Appdelegate.m (sigabrt error)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I am getting a SIGABRT error and i am getting really irritated can you please assist me. I know that the error is in result of something in the app delegate. I went through the code a couple of times and checked the storyboard but there are no issues there. Even Parse is properly compiling.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation AppDelegate 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//  Parse Initialization

.....


//Custom Stuff Initialization

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Assign tab bar item with titles
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

tabBarItem1.title = @"Dashboard";
tabBarItem1.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -5.5);
tabBarItem2.title = @"Interactions";
tabBarItem2.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -5.5);
tabBarItem3.title = @"Messages";
tabBarItem3.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -5.5);
tabBarItem4.title = @"Me";
tabBarItem4.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -5.5);

[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pen_sIMG.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pen_usIMG.png"]];
[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comment_sIMG.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comment_usIMG.png"]];
[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message_sIMG.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message_usIMG.png"]];
[tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_sIMG.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_usIMG.png"]];


// Change the tab bar background
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarBg-icns.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarBg-selc.png"]];

// Change the title color of tab bar items
UIColor *titleNormColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:137/255.0 green:137/255.0 blue:137/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   titleNormColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


UIColor *titleHighlightedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:73/255.0 green:130/255.0 blue:202/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   titleHighlightedColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


return YES;
}



@end
```

Comment: No one can help you. You need to post the complete error. Do you get the crash while running in the debugger? Which line of code causes the problem?

Comment: Note: You should probably not post your Parse app id and client key. I suggest you remove those from your question.

Comment: Did you enable zombies in your debug scheme and add a breakpoint for Objective-C exceptions? That should give you more information on where and why the error is happening.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below line of your code is wrong

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

because **`self.window.rootViewController;`** will only returns **UIViewController**. Not a **UITabBarController**

Correct code is

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController;
```

Comment: If the root view controller is in fact a `UITabBarController` then the original code line is fine.